# angularjs: how to disable directive for a specific element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, highlight.js

I want to show a code snippet of how to use a directive. However, the directive exists in this application, so when I have

```
<pre>
    <code>
        <bar-foo>bar foo</bar-foo>
    </code>
</pre>
```

I'm using [highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org/), but angular doesn't care much and applies the directive to the bar-foo element. How can I disable the directive for that specific element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [ng-non-bindable](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angNonBindable):

```
<pre ng-non-bindable>
    <code>
        <bar-foo>bar foo</bar-foo>
    </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: @Michael Thanks. Corrected in the post.

Answer (score 1):

What I would is to add an attribute to `<bar-foo>` element like `<bar-foo data-is-disabled="{{true}}" >`. In the  directive I would add at the very top of the `link` method:

```
if ($scope.$eval(attrs.isDisabled)) return ;`
```

If I needed to make sure to clear all content probably before return I could do something like:

```
element.replaceWith('')
```

Comment: how will that work if you have (for example) 'transclude: true'. You cannot stop that (I think)

Comment: that is why I included the element.replaceWith('') @JeanlucaScaljeri I think that will take care of it but don't guess it try it :)

Comment: although this might work, it is not the way to go, you don't want to change your directive because you want to show code on a demo page

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri I was thinking what if you have your directive in an ng-repeat and on alternate rows you want to disable your directive. Is it possible to do that differently?